# In express-session, how do can you sync Socket.io 4.x session when Express changes session data?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, express-session

I have an Express 4.17.1 app that uses express-session 1.17.2 and Socket.io 4.1.2.

To share Express's session with Socket.io, before a connection is made, we usually do:

```
import session from "../../loaders/session.js";

const init = function (io) {
  io.use(function (socket, next) {
    session(socket.request, {}, next);
  });
  io.on("connection", /* bla bla bla */);
};

export default init;
```

The problem is that whenever Express routes update session data, Socket.io session doesn't sync, it keeps the original values in what we defined in `io.use`. Is there a way to call a sync/update method or something?

(The reason I'm asking is that answers online are all for Socket.io 3.x and there is little documentation for using Socket.io with express-session)

Comment: Just curious, how are you using express sessions? What I mean by that is what connection does the session have with socket.io? I ask because what happens when a user gets disconnected, is the session data sent back again and associated with the socketID on the socket.io server?

Comment: I only use one server for socket.io and express. I don't use the socket ID. When I update session from socket.io, I use socket.request.session.save(). I don't know what "associated with the socketID" means. The connection between the session and socket.io is simply the io.use function, it kinda makes a "copy" of the session data, but doesn't sync when the session is updated elsewhere. I have Express routes which assign properties to session, and I need a way to update the socket.io session accordingly.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I actually found the solution, you need to call session.save() to send to session and session.reload() to get from session